# Задача для диплома: web + math

Tags: веб-программирование, математика

какую задачу можно взять в качестве диплома, чтобы она объединяла `web`, математику и решение которой было бы актуально для определенной аудитории? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Отрисовщик формул. Как на википедии или в разделе математика хешкода. Если это будет просто - тогда редактор формул (как в Word или MathCad), но с возможностью экспорта  в популярные форматы (картинкой, tex).

Дополнительные усложнения: прорисовка по заданным стандартам, приведение к стандарту (к примеру - точка или запятая для дробной части, логарифм по разному обозначается в разных стандартах).

Comment: достаточно хорошая идея!, я ее поддерживаю. Добавлю еще возможность либо перевод в программный код, либо построение графика по формуле (это чтобы математика была)

Comment: можно ещё интересней. У студентов первых курсов по программированию часто бывает задача по табулированию функции. Ну так вот, сделать программу, которая будет по заданной функции делать табуляцию, строить графики, генерировать несколько версий программы на разных языках, готовить отчет в ворде.

Comment: Да,интересно,спасибо

Comment: А чем вас имеющиеся отрисовщики не устраивают?

Comment: а вот на это в дипломе Вы и найдете ответ. В дипломе должен быть обзор существующих решений и объяснение, почему представленное решение лучше.

Comment: Правда,еще на 2 или 3 курсе я уже писал программу, которая бы строила график любой функции и помимо этого программировал много других вычислительных методов.Мне бы хотелось,конечно,что-нибудь посложнее, просто все же самой математики и каких-то сложных вычислений тут нет.Но спасибо за идею.

Comment: Если хотите серьезной математики, обратитесь к моделированию. Взаимодействие веществ, скажем какой-нибудь визуальное пособие для школьников.

Answer (score 0):

Визуализация разнообразных фракталов в 3Д в браузере - весьма любопытная тема, я считаю.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите редактор интерактивных карт.
Тут с математикой свяжете все при вычислении координат объектов, их масштабирование с матрицами. 
И очень даже актуально. Сам делал такой редактор, правда не для диплома.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите 3d визуализатор для музыки. Математика будет использоваться для просчёта спктра/диаграммы трека, веб будет использоваться для вывода.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите расчет коммунальных платежей с MySql